# Visitor pattern - visiting super class before visiting class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have a class structure containing a base class and several extending classes. There are multiple 'Actions' i want to perform on each class which depends on their type - which is why i want to use the visitor pattern. Implementing the actions on the classes itself requires some dependencies which i want to avoid pushing to the event class.

This is a simplification of my current class structure that i want to move into the visitor pattern :

```
class BaseEvent{

    public BaseEvent(SomeDependency d){...}
    String baseAttrA;

    public void doActionA(){
       d.doSomeAction(baseAttrA);
    }
}


class EventA extends BaseEvent{
      String eventAAttribute;
      public EventA(SomeOtherDependency d){...}    
      public void doActionA(){ 
        super.doActionA();
        d.doOtherAction(eventAAttribute);
      }    

}
```

I have several more classes that extends BaseEvent and several more actions.
Please note :
EventA(and following) actions requires the same action to be done on Base event .
Same action on BaseEvent/EventA/other requires a different dependency and attribute. it is a different logic that is called on the same scenario.

Optimally, i'd like to have a class for each Action (using the visitor pattern), which recieves the specific dependencies it requires for the actions and contains all the logic in one class. Something like

```
public class ActionAVisitor{
     public ActionAVisitor(SomeDependency d1, SomeOtherDependency d2){...}

   public void visit(BaseEvent event){
       d1.doSomeAction(event.getBaseAttribute());  
  }

  public void visit(EventA event){
      // Missing call to super.doActionA()
      d2.doDifferentAction(event.getEventAAttribute());
  }
```

The problem is that now there is no call to super.doActionA(), which can be solved by calling an ugly `this.visit((BaseEvent)event);` instead of the commented line. But this have to be added on each visit function, in all visitors.... which feels wrong.

Is there any other design pattern \ addition to the visitor pattern that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Implementing the actions on the classes itself requires some dependencies which i want to avoid pushing to the event class.

I would create interfaces around these dependencies that you don't want Event classes to know about, and make the Event classes depend on your (lightweight) interfaces instead. Dependency Injection is a simple and straightforward approach to reduce coupling, compared to the Visitor Pattern; and it leaves you the freedom to easily expand your Event hierarchy in the future.

Remember, you can make the Event dependencies look however you want by wrapping them in interfaces that convey domain meaning and an appropriate level of abstraction. Or consider the Decorator Pattern if you want to add some behavior to the existing dependencies.